# How to check if exists a list of ids

Tags: sql, postgresql

I'm looking to do a single query which returns if exists (true or false) a list of id instead of just one.

The common *exist* query is like next

```
select exist(select 1 from one_table where id_table = 'some_value')
```

And I would like a query which check multiple values. It would be something like next

```
select exist(select 1 from one_table 
             where id_table in('some_value_1', '...'))
```

But in the case I'm looking for all Ids must exist.

Comment: It's essential to declare whether `id_table` is defined `UNIQUE` or `PRIMARY KEY`. Best add a table definition and the Postgres version to *any* question. And do you provide a *list* of values, a *set* (like a table) or an *array*?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

One method uses `count(*)`:

```
select <n> = (select count(*) from one_table where id_table in ('some_value_1', '...')
```

The value `<n>` would be the number of ids.

Another method is to use a sequence of `exists`:

```
select (exists (select 1 from one_table where id_table = id1) and
        exists (select 1 from one_table where id_table = id2) and
        . . .
       )
```

Comment: That's what I'm looking for. In terms of performance which one is better?

Comment: Either should be fine if you have an index on `one_able(id_table)`.  The second probably has a slight performance advantage because of short-circuiting, but you would need to try it out on your system to see if this really makes a difference.